# htaccess rewrite rule with condition and rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, exception

I have a site that currently redirects to the public folder from root /
like so...

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I would like to add an exception for a system folder that needs to redirect to a different folder named 000999

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system [NC]
 RewriteRule ^system/(.*)$ /000999 [L,NC]
```

However the exception whether placed after "Rewrite Base" or anywhere else fails to redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description and the example I understand that if the "folder" system is requested, regardless of the path below, there should be an internal rewrite to the folder /000999? Not a redirection? And the path should be ignored?

This should do, note that I also fixed a couple of other issues with your current setup:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?system/(.*)$ /000999 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /public/$1 [END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).